# Custom carousel slider with slick jquery

Tags: jquery, css, slider, slick.js

I'm trying to develop custom carousel slider for HTML

Ref: https://streamiumtheme.com/

[Attached Reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uVTsK.png)

Can anyone help me to find out this slider?

Answer (score 1):

check this out , you might find something useful,its easy to find out by practicing the samples in this site:
http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/

Comment: I'm really looking for mouser over transform/transition effects on reference https://streamiumtheme.com/

Answer (score 0):

You can try the "Inspect" feature of the web browser to discover it yourself. In this case the answer is Slick: http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/.

[image]